# centos 6.5 python 2.7 can not find pygtk that python 2.6 sees fine

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygtk, centos6.5, tryton

I have installed python 2.7 beside 2.6 on a CentOS 6.5 os.  The particular application I want to install needs 2.7, but it also needs pygtk (as well as other stuff).  If I start an interpreter with 2.6, it imports pygtk fine.  But if I start an interpreter with 2.7 it can not find what it needs [pygtk].

There are plenty of helpful posts that address installing duplicate versions of python on CentOS 6, but could someone please help me make the python 2.7 find the other stuff [pygtk]?

Why else would I want to install python 2.7 beside python 2.6 on CentOS if I didn't want to use a bunch of the standard things in both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately packages that are installed with one minor version of Python are not able to be used with another minor version (as an example, version 2.7.8 is major version 2, minor version 7, micro version 8). Different micro versions are compatible with one another, so packages installed with 2.7.3 will work with 2.7.8, for example. So, while it may seem redundant, anything that you have with 2.6 you'll have to reinstall with 2.7 in order to work with it under 2.7. This is due to changes in the ABI from version to version, and other "under the hood" differences.

Comment: This is one of the things Python 3.2+ (and pip 1.5+) has improved; you can set up a shared site-packages used by, e.g., both 3.2 and 3.4, and pure-Python modules that don't use any post-3.2 features, and even C extension modules if they stick to the [stable ABI](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0384/), will work. That doesn't help you with 2.6 and 2.7, of course.

Comment: but how do you install pygtk? I have yet to find an answer. `yum install pygtk2` says it's already installed (guess it's only looking at the standard python 2.6 installation that came with centOS)

Comment: @KevinS. have you tried `pip install pygtk` using pip from Python 2.7?

Comment: @MattDMo tried it first thing but got an error: Collecting pyGTK
  Using cached pygtk-2.24.0.tar.bz2
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ********************************************************************
    * Building PyGTK using distutils is only supported on windows. *
    * To build PyGTK in a supported way, read the INSTALL file.    *
    ********************************************************************
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-0taGep/pyGTK/

Comment: @KevinS. you'll have to download the `.tar.gz` from PyPI and build it yourself outside of `pip`. Ask a new question if you need help.